# Why do we dig holes and fill them in with concrete?

Tags: concrete

I'm watching construction of a new building across from my office. The old building has been demolished and the demo team has completed taking everything away and a new company has come in to start working.

The new building will have a five floor underground parking lot and 19 floors above it. The site used to be an industrial area and sits on what used to be marsh.

Now for the question: The excavators are digging holes maybe 6 to 10 feet deep (hard to tell from my vantage point), supporting the hole with vertical walls and filling them with concrete then covering them with dirt. Several of these are along the perimeter but at least one is in the middle of the construction site. What are these for?

The only thing I could add that might help is to say that they appear to have surveyed for underground utilities and appear to have marked telco and sewage pipes judging by the orange and green markings. At at least one spot they indicated 14'. I'm not sure if it's at all related to the holes though.

[image: Construction]
[image: Construction]

Comment: How big are the holes (guestimate)? What shape are they?

Comment: Are these starting at the bottom of the 5th subbasement or at ground level?

Comment: @Wasabi I think they are about 20 ft long, 6 ft wide and 6 to 10 ft deep.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft These are being dug at ground level.

Comment: Could you possibly [edit] your question with a picture of the jobsite? Digging and filling holes at ground level when you're still going to dig five floors down is making no sense to me, especially given the size of the holes...

Comment: Yeah, given that they're still going to dig five stories down, I have no idea what's going on.